# Dont Recieve $_POST variables after Servermigration

Tags: php, post, oscommerce

I moved my osCommerce shop to my new Plesk-Server, and after that I don't receive any $_POST-Variables.

But when I moved it back it started working again.

I created a test script:

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $_POST );
echo "</pre>";
?>

<form method="POST" action="login.php?act=do">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And that result is empty. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the expected value in $_REQUEST?

Comment: Only the $_get parameter....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

In plesk the edfault URL was set with: www.*
But my form was send to url withour "www"!